# Couldnt not find function "cc" Knit PDF in R

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio, knitr

When trying to Knit PDF on R Studio i get this error. `cc()` is a function from package `CCA()`, which I've installed and loaded previously. It runs perfectly in the console as does this other function: `plt.cc()`, which needs the same package and library, too.

```
Quitting from lines 125-128 (Preview-ecc331f1f51.Rmd)  Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "cc" Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval Execution halted
```

Need some help guys, i'm 'bout to crack my display !

Comment: Did you call `library(CCA)` in your document?

Comment: Expanding on @RichardScriven's comment, knitr runs in a _completely new/clean environment_. You have to load all packages/data/objects you need within the Rmd. It's one of the core components of knitr/Rmds being reproducible works.

Comment: @hrbrmstr What you write is often repeated, but it's not exactly/always true. It is true when the knitting is initiated using RStudio's "Compile PDF" button, but it is *not* true when calling `knit()` or `knit2pdf()` from the command line (with the default argument `envir = parent.frame()`.

Comment: @user2706569 it was fairly obvious the OP is pressing the button in RStudio

Comment: @hrbrmstr Yes. But thinking of future readers I think it's good to emphasize what applies in *this case* vs. *in general*. This is obvious for you and me but probably not for people who are new to the topic.

Comment: that's usually the case provided the OPs actually post complete/specific questions. SO isn't a `man` page repository.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Yes, SO isn't a `man`page repository, but material on SO should be helpful for future readers. If an advice relies an something that is not clearly evident from the question, this should be mentioned, I think. I don't want to annoy you, I'd just like to create some awareness for this issue because I often read answers that seem to be misleading regarding the environment `knitr` works in.

Comment: Thank you Guys, very helpful. I´ll try to be more specific next time !

Answer (score 0):

You should do this

```
require(CCA)
cc(SOMETHING) ...
```

Comment: Thank you!  I´ve just included require(CCA) inside the Chunk and runs all

Comment: you should only do that on the 1st chunk, other wise you are reloading the library without efficiency